# A model without any hidden layer shows 98 percent accuracy.Why?

Tags: machine-learning

I have build two models one is without any hidden layer and I used softmax at the output. And other is with one hidden layer and in hidden layer I used sigmoid as an activation function. I was expecting that the model with one hidden layer will give better performance but I am getting almost same performance in both models. I was wondering why the model without any hidden layer is showing such a high performance? In both cases I have used large amount of data to train the network.
Here is the out of the model without any hidden layer. Can someone please guide me why it is showing such a high accuracy. In literature I have read that deeper network has more expressive power.

```
`step: 4400, train_acc: 0.99, test_acc: 0.996
step: 4500, train_acc: 1.0, test_acc: 0.996
step: 4600, train_acc: 1.0, test_acc: 0.998
step: 4700, train_acc: 0.99, test_acc: 0.998
step: 4800, train_acc: 1.0,test_acc: 1.0
step: 4900, train_acc: 0.99,test_acc: 0.996`
```

Comment: No free lunch theorem?

Comment: Very simple data?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point?

Comment: I'm performing a classification problem. where I have to divide it into two classes and I'm using fully connected network. I'm new in machine learning field. I'm surprised why two networks are showing 98 percent performance

Comment: Does 98 percent of your data belong to one class?

Comment: No I gave equal amount of data as input from both classes. 98 percent is my model's accuracy

Comment: Try a different simpler method, see if this persists.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a programming question.

Comment: what do you mean by simpler method?How I can simplify.My model is already so simple without any hidden layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that your data set is linearly separable , which means a linear classifier can be used to get good accuracy on training set if not 100%. one neuron is all it takes to find a decision boundary for a linearly separable problem. adding more layers and more neurons in each layer with none linear activation functions, is only for the sake of making more complex classifiers for more complex patterns.
conclusion, if you get the most accuracy that is possible, what is more that you expect a more complex network would offer? computation cost of course.